# custom error suggetion in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#

i have an application where i am using custom error in web config file it is working fine for 404,500,403 error status and redirect to error page if above error found.but my problem is if i got object reference not set to an instance of an object and null error exception or divide by zero exception it is not redirecting to error page.any suggestions is greatly appreciated.i have tried below code

```
enter code here <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Index"/>
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/Index"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/Index"/>

</customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside adding custom error in system.web you should also enable custom error in webserver.

```
  <system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto">
    <remove statusCode="403" />
    <remove statusCode="404" />
    <remove statusCode="500" />
    <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="Error403.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="Error404.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="Error500.aspx" />
  </httpErrors>
```

Comment: when i got object reference not set to an instance of an object and null error exception or divide by zero exception error it is not redirecting to error page.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <error statusCode="500" path="/error/index" responseMode="Redirect" />
</httpErrors>
```

to the `<system.webServer>` section.